# How do I make a photo change between the days of the week?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a lot of code that I made so far but I can't get the load() function to work:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<!-- Page resizer -->
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Optional theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<!-- Date -->
<script>
var d = new Date();
var days = ["Sunday","Monday","Tuesday","Wednesday","Thursday","Friday","Saturday"];
document.getElementById("date").innerHTML = days[d.getDay()];
</script>

<!-- Gif changer -->
<script>
function changegif() {
  var gif;
  if (days = Sunday) {
    gif = "/img/sunday.gif";
  } else if (days = Monday) {
    gif = "/img/monday.gif";
  } else if (days = Tuesday) {
    gif = "/img/tuesday.gif";
  } else if (days = Wednesday) {
    gif = "/img/wednesday.gif";
  } else if (days = Thursday) {
    gif = "/img/thursday.gif";
  } else if (days = Friday) {
    gif = "/img/friday.gif";
  } else if (days = Saturday) {
    gif = "/img/saturday.gif";
  }
}

function load() {
  document.getElementById('gif').src = changegif();
}
</script>
</head>
<body onload="load()">

<!-- More date stuff -->
<style>
.image { 
   position: relative; 
   width: 100%; /* for IE 6 */
}

h2 { 
   position: absolute; 
   top: 150px; 
   left: 0; 
   width: 100%; 
}

h2 span { 
   color: white; 
   font: bold 24px/45px Helvetica, Sans-Serif; 
   letter-spacing: -1px;  
   background: rgb(0, 0, 0); /* fallback color */
   background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
   padding: 10px; 
}

h1 { 
   position: absolute; 
   top: 200px; 
   left: 0; 
   width: 100%; 
}

h1 span { 
   color: white; 
   font: bold 24px/45px Helvetica, Sans-Serif; 
   letter-spacing: -1px;  
   background: rgb(0, 0, 0); /* fallback color */
   background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
   padding: 10px; 
}
</style>
<div class="image">
<img src="#" id="gif">
<h2><span>Enjoy Your</span></h2>
<br>
<h1 id="date"><span></span></h1>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

If anybody knows what I'm doing wrong please tell me. I have tried integrating the functions into a button but it still didn't work.

Comment: For starters, `days = Sunday` is an assignment, not an equality test; you need `==`.  And `days` is an array, so `days == Sunday` or any other day will never be true.

Comment: Even then, you're checking the array `days` against an unknown entity called `Sunday`. You'd have to do something like `if (days[d.getDay()] == "Sunday") ...`. You are also not returning `gif` in `changegif()` so `....src = changegif();` fails.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove all your own `<script>`s, then use this:

```
function load() {
    var day = ["Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday"][new Date().getDay()];
    document.getElementById("date").innerHTML = day;
    document.getElementById('gif').src = "/img/" + day.toLowerCase() + ".gif";
}
```

Comment: Thank you, soo much. I would have never gotten this if it weren't for you.(but what do expect from a 13-year-old kid)

Comment: @MasonKukosky You're welcome, and keep at it :) Took me quite long to get there.

Answer (score 0):

To explain all the mistakes:

- `=` assigns; it does not compare.
- `changegif` doesn’t return anything, so `document.getElementById('gif').src = changegif();` will always set it to `undefined` (assuming no other errors).
- `Sunday` and others are undeclared variable names; they only work as strings: `"Sunday"`.
- `days` is not a single day, it’s the whole array, so comparing it to a single day won’t work.

`changegif` can be simplified to:

```
function changegif(){
  return "/img/"
    + days[d.getDay()].toLowerCase()
    + ".gif";
}
```

Or use [the answer by Chris G](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41515384/how-do-i-make-a-photo-change-between-the-days-of-the-week/41515507#41515507).